# How would animal husbandry and domestication change if animals could talk and think

Tags: magic, society, fauna

In the world where Intelligent and speech are much more common and any animal bigger Then rat size rodent Not only has human level intelligence but the ability to speak and understand human language. I'm wondering How/if the domestication of animals could start in this situation?

To clarify the world has always been this way.

Comment: Are you asking how/if domestication of animals would have started in prehistory if all animals are intelligent?  (Note that "domestication" is defined as controlling the reproduction of a species to human benefit rather than merely taming an animal, it is hard to see an intelligent species going along with it voluntarily.)  Or did all animals magically become intelligent at some point in history - if so, what period?

Comment: It's not obvious to me that animals _can't_ think.

Comment: @Tom  Of course lots of animals probably think but they don't think with the same intelligence as humans obviously.

Comment: The question would require a speculative book to answer, or more likely a volume for every climate on Earth. Giving all 1+ kg animals language and intellect would require working out all the resultant societies of wolves, lions, gazelles, kangaroos, tiger snakes, eagles etc etc and then working out the possible alliances between them and... The only part that is moderately certain is that if the massive biological cost of human intelligence (long maturation) no longer gives an intelligence advantage over other species then there won't be any humans to domesticate anything.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the length of answer required is both speculative and far too long for this site.

Comment: Surely you've been on this site long enough to know that questions of the form "_everything has radically changed. how is life different?_" are frowned upon!

Comment: Hey Wolves! Come hunt with us, live with us, and share the warmth of our fires. All we ask is to be able to do some selective breeding. We promise we won't turn any of your descendants into little bug eyed things that can fit into a small bag for at least ten thousand years.